# PHP variable is always empty after passing it a value

Tags: php, sqlite

I've created this PHP files that should read a python scripts with arguments and process this script.

```
$error = array();
$data = array();
include("./includes/common.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'  && isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $lbl10 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lbl10', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $filePath = uploadFile('C:/xampp/htdocs/GraduationProject/images/test/');

    if(empty($error)){

        $output = shell_exec("C:/xampp/htdocs/GraduationProject/includes/train.py {$lbl10} {$filePath}");
        if($output){
            $ret = $db->getData("WHERE ID='{$output}'");
            while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
                $data = $row;
            }
        }

        $success = "Data saved successfully!";
    }
}else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    $error[] = "Required Field Missing";
}

$db->close();
```

The PHP file should outcome some results according to the python script processing with the database after this if statement:

```
<?php if(!empty($data)){ ?>
```

But nothing happens as `$data` seems to be always empty.

Comment: Why not your check the $row and $data value?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is here

```
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            $data = $row;
        }
```

because of each iteration overwrite $data value.

I think you need a different behavior. Maybe

```
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
```

or

```
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            if (null != $row) {
                $data = $row;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think, he should add `while (...){ $data[] = $ret->fetchArray(...); }`